# python - read float values from Tiff file

Tags: python, opencv, floating-point, tiff, 32-bit

I need to work with *32 bit tiff files with floating point values*. It's a special file that contains *4 layers with floating point values* from a depth measurement camera.

I have already tried `imageio`, `tifffile` and `OpenCV`. In `opencv` I set the attribute `flag=cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` as well, but nothing works. It is always imported as an 8 bit integer.

Is there any way to do it in Python? I know it works in `Matlab`, but I don't have the license.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Edit: Sample image: https://ufile.io/fn1j2js6

Edit2: New sample with real 32bit: https://ufile.io/r17sxo0t

Comment: Please share a file.

Comment: Your link doesn't appear to work.

Comment: `tifffile` reads/writes float32 images for me!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks so far - I've uploaded a sample with another file hoster

Comment: @SamMason Thanks, but it didn't work either for me :/ Or have you used any special parameters?

Comment: Your image has 4 channels of 8-bits each. You can check it with `exiftool`.

Comment: yup, the file size is consistent with 8 bits per pixel not 32bpp.  532*460*4 == 978880, while the file size is 979066

Comment: @Jefferson presumably Matlab is trying to be "helpful" when converting data to floats while Python is just giving you the data as is

Comment: @SamMason 8 bits per *"sample"* 

Comment: @MarkSetchell, oops, yup, that would be the correct term!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys!! Due to this we discovered a bug in the export function of our software. Now I have an actual 32bit tiff file, that's readable by imageio, tifffile and rasterio (not by opencv though).

Comment: Enjoy your week!

Comment: If you update your sample, maybe we can figure out why cv2 doesn't work?

Comment: Hey @MarkRansom alright lets do it : ) I've uploaded another file. Tested with opencv v3.4 and v4.6 ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use scikit image. if its a normal tiff file

```
from skimage import io
my_img = io.imread('myimage.tiff')
```

Alternatively if your tiff file is a georeferenced image. You can use gdal

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

ds = gdal.Open("myimage.tiff")

myarr1 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
myarr2 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray())
myarr3 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray())

myimage = np.dstack([myarr1, myarr2, myarr3])
```